# Need Filter to calendar list i.e for calendar.aspx page

Tags: calendar, filter

For Calendar List - web part connections doesn't work and query string doesn't work. So I am out of options here.

Can any one guide me to how to filter the calendar list data in calendar.aspx.

I am open to any solution - JQuery, Visual Studio, 3rd party tools like Bamboo or any other.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to display? Can you create static filtered calendar views (with dynamic date filtering based on [Today]) and use those?

Answer (score 1):

I have a built a web part which has a drop down and button, which I added in calendar.aspx of the calendar list. In the button click event I have added the following code. I am just passing the drop down selected value to the SPView CAML Query. This works fine.

Please let me know if there is a better way.

SPList oList = oSite.Lists["CustomCalendar"];
                        SPView oView = oList.Views["Calendar"];
                        oView.Query = "" +[Dropdown Selected Value]+ "
";
                        oView.Update();
Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.query.aspx